# A family of functions graphing

Tags: algebra-precalculus

(1.) A family of functions is given. Graph all the given members of the family in the viewing rectangles indicated.
f(x) = (x − c)^2

$$c = 1, -1, 3, -3; [−5, 5] \times [−10, 10]$$

(2.) A family of functions is given. Graph all the given members of the family in the viewing rectangles indicated.
f(x) = cx^2

$$c = 1, 1/2, 2, −1, −2;[−5, 5] \times [−10, 10]$$

Please explain how I would graph these.

Comment: Let me ask this. Do you know how the value of $c$ affects the shape of the graph for each of these examples?

Comment: Honestly, no. Please explain

Comment: I just posted an answer/hint. Please read it and let me know if you can understand what I mean.

Comment: Ok, so the values would would be substituted in c in f(x) = (x-c)^2?

Comment: Each value of $c$ defines a different function, and each one has a different graph. The graphs are all similar, but somewhat different. The point of the problem is for you to understand how the particular form makes the functions graph change as $c$ changes. In every case, the graph is a parabola, but in (1) the various parabolas are shifted horizontally by $c$ units, and in (2) the parabolas are stretched vertically by a factor of $c$. Fix the given value of $c$, make a table for $x$-values in $[-5,5]$, and plot the points. You should see it.

Comment: (Continued) But knowing how $c$ affects each function, you can just start with the basic graph of $y=x^2$ and shift or stretch the graph to get the desired result without making any tables.

Comment: Is semi-logarithmic paper allowed ? :->

Answer (score 1):

**Huge Hints:** For (1), it is generally true that $(x,y)$ lies on the graph of $y=f(x)$ exactly when $(x+c,y)$ lies on the graph of $y=f(x-c)$.

For (2), it is generally true that $(x,y)$ lies on the graph of $y=f(x)$ exactly when $(x,cy)$ lies on the graph of $y=cf(x)$.

In both cases, $f(x)=x^2$.